# FB CORS problem error with comments in React.js

Tags: reactjs, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have problem to add FB comments section to my website where I using React.JS and its facebook library 'react-facebook'.
There is a code.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Head from '../components/Head';
import Navigation from '../components/common/Navigation';
import Footer from '../components/common/Footer';
import Content from '../components/common/Content';
import { useRef} from 'react';
import { Comments, FacebookProvider } from 'react-facebook';

export const Heading = styled.h2`
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
    font-display: swap;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem !important;
    margin-top: 2rem;
`;

function OpeningPage() {

    let isAuth = useRef<string | null>(sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'));

    return (
        <>
            <Head title={'Zoo Admin'} />
            <Navigation />
            <>
                <Content>
                    <Heading className={'heading'}>
                        {!isAuth.current ? 'Basic zoo admin app' : 'Hey, You are logged in !'}
                    </Heading>
                    <FacebookProvider appId="846385830401827">
                        <Comments href="http://www.facebook.com" />
                    </FacebookProvider>


                </Content>
            </>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default OpeningPage;
```

I have this error at console and don't have any clue.

```
Access to script at 'about:blank' (redirected from 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js') from origin 'http://localhost:4001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, isolated-app, brave, https, chrome-untrusted, data, chrome-extension, chrome.
Facebook.ts:139     
GET about:blank net::ERR_FAILED
```

How can I please fix this error and make comments visible?

I tried change app mode from development to online. This doesn't work.